# Update adapter when database changes

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm making a simple app that has a main activity with a `RecyclerView`. The main activity gets notes from a `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and sets the notes into the adapter.

There is other activity that creates new notes and record them in the db. There is not 'Save' button so the save work is done in the `onStop()` method like this:

```
    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        val textInputEditTitle : TextInputEditText = this.findViewById(R.id.textInputNoteTitle)
        val textInputEditText : TextInputEditText = this.findViewById(R.id.textInputNoteText)
        note = Note(textInputEditTitle.text.toString(), textInputEditText.text.toString())
        val dbHandler = DbHandler(this)
        dbHandler.insertNote(note)
        dbHandler.close()
    }
```

The problem is when returning to the main activity the RecyclerView doesn't show the new note.

I have tried this in the main activity:

```
    override fun onResume(){
        super.onResume()
        notes = dbHandler.getNotes()
        for(note in notes) Log.d(TAG, note.toString())
        noteAdapter.setData(notes)
        noteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

But the the log shows only the old notes, not the new one.

Ideally I'd like to call to update the data of the noteApater from the insert update and delete methods in the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class so every time the the db is updated the adapter is updated too. I can't do this because the second activity would have to know the adapter to inicialice the db.

Any sugestions?

Comment: you can use Room DB and get a observer from DB and just observe it in your activity
if you are new to android Room you can use this android official tutorial to learn things - https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#0

Answer (score 0):

you can use Room DB and get a observer from DB and just observe it in your activity
if you are new to android Room you can use this android official tutorial to learn things - https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#0